# how to get query in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating a query like this

```
    $om = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $qb = $om->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('ProbusQuoteExtraBundle:Quote', 'q')
            ->select('q', 'b')
            ->join('q.booking', 'b')
            ->orderBy('q.id', 'asc')
            ->where("q.startDate >= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')) . "'")
            ->andWhere("q.startDate <= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . "'")
    ;
```

i want to check if i created correct query or not by using this

```
echo $qb->getQuery();
```

but it gives error.

Comment: "but it gives error" so please display that error...

Comment: Maybe because you are trying to use Query object as a string, because getQuery() method will return object. Try with getDQL() or use var_dump instead echo.

Comment: echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL(); might help. Also, remember the debugging toolbar in your development environment shows all the queries that have run.

Comment: thanks all for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check your statement in DQL or SQL you can do this by
calling `->getSQL()`, or `->getDQL()` on `$qb->getQuery()`;

Also I recommend installing xdebug and using `var_dump()`:

```
$sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();
$dql = $qb->getQuery()->getDQL();
var_dump($sql);
var_dump($dql);
```

It will print both, a SQL and DQL dump of your QueryBuilder

And since we're at it, instead of injecting your parameters by concatenation use the QueryBuilders `->setParameters()` method:

```
->where("q.startDate >= :startDate")
->andWhere("q.startDate <= :endDate")
->setParameters(array(
         'startDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')), 
         'endDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
))
```

You can find more on that in the [Doctrine2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query).

Comment: thanks. it worked. one more question, how can i read and display result after query is executed?

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
print_r($result);

Comment: this is exactly how. This is your mapped result.

Comment: its giving error object of class datetime could not be converted to string

Comment: that means your result is, or contains a datetime object.
Install xdebug, and use var_dump to see what you get.

A possibility for a string representation of a DateTime Object ist ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). Check the documentation http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php